# MapReduce Job with HAR file input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, har

I have created a `HAR` file containing multiple small input files. For running a map reduce job with a single input file, this willbe the command:

`hadoop jar <jarname> <packagename.classname> <input> <output>`

But if in case the above `<input>` is a HAR file the what will be the command such that all the contents of the `HAR` file is considered as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is a HAR file then in the place of input the following has to be given

```
har:///hdfs path to har file
```

Since hadoop archives will be exposed as filesystem, mapreduce will be able to use all the files in hadoop archives as input.

Comment: "hadoop archives will be exposed as filesystem" is the notable thing here. Thanks.